# Progress bar remains at 0% although although epochs are trained while using simple transformers

Tags: python, machine-learning, simpletransformers

Here is my code:

```
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel, ClassificationArgs
model_args = ClassificationArgs(output_dir='test_dir',
                                overwrite_output_dir=True,
                                num_train_epochs=3)
model = ClassificationModel("bert", "bert-base-uncased", use_cuda= False, num_labels=9, args=model_args)
model.train_model(train_df)
```

For some reason progress bar remains at zero even after epochs training is completed. Why this is the case?
[image: For some reason progress bar remains at zero even after epochs training is completed.]